# jquery populating a dialog checkbox with the value of a table checkbox

Tags: javascript, jquery, checkbox

I am attempting to populate a checkbox in a dialog based upon the checkbox in a selected table row. The page has multiple tables. The tables have the same columns and a variable number of rows. Each row has one checkbox. When clicking on the row's edit icon, I open a dialog window. I am attempting to set the property of the dialog property checkbox to the property of the row property and am not having success: I have read every jquery checkbox posting and tried the solutions. These are my last 2 tries:

```
    $('.ui-icon-pencil').click(function(e) {
      var initialRow = $(this).parent().parent();
     var $thisFieldset = $("#bookmark-data-fieldset");
     var urlid = $("td:first", initialRow).text();

   /*default dialog checkbox to not checked*/
    $('#dialoggoalstatus').removeAttr('checked');
    var urlname = $("td:nth-child(2)", initialRow).text();
    var newurlname = urlname.trim(); 
    var goal_date = $("td:nth-child(3)", initialRow).text();
    $('#bookmark-goaldate').val(goal_date);
   /* populate the dialog checkbox with the property of the 
   row checkbox*/       
    $("#dialoggoalstatus").prop($("td:nth-child(4)",  
    initialRow).find(':checkbox').prop('checked'));
   /* I also tried this*/
  $("#dialoggoalstatus").prop($(initialRow).
   find('td input:eq(4)').is(':checked'));
```

This did not work. Can you help me identify what I am missing?

In addition, I attempting to then populate the table with the selection of made in the dialog form.

I am using this:

```
     var goalid = $("td:first", initialRow).text();
    $("td:nth-child(2)",initialRow).text($("#namefield").val());
    $("td:nth-child(3)", initialRow).text($("#datefield").val());
    $("td:nth-child(4)", initialRow).
     prop($( "#dialoggoalstatus").prop('checked'));
```

This also is not working.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I would use debugger in chrome or FF to go through each line one-by-one if you havent yet..

Comment: Can you share your HTML? or maybe create a jsfiddle to show the problem?

Comment: yes please make a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.com) from scratch with the simplest code illustrating the problem